# Enabling publishing infrastructure feature by default in sharepoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I know how to in the settings activate publishing feature on a site but is it possible to have this by default when a new site is created from the UI?

I have some customized stylesheets and when a new team site is created it doesn't load these but instead looks like a sharepoint site out of the box. When I go to settings and activate publishing features the page reloads with the custom stylesheets. I wish to not have to do this every time a new site is created. Is there a solution to this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could either:

1. Build a site template (can't remember if these store feature activations)
2. Build a custom site definition, and activate the features you need
3. Build a stapling feature to tie your feature to the site definition

Comment: Preferably the user would be able to click New Site and select whichever template/definition they want and the site has publishing activated. I don't want to build a custom site template for every possible site type in SP 2010.

Comment: do you really want to activate the publishing feature on all site definitions? team sites, search center, mysite, etc...

Comment: This isn't really a solution. Questioning the motive behind needing to get something done isn't helpful. What would be useful is information on how to create a stapling feature. This particular issue is bothersome, and a good example of how SP2010 has taken a step backward from SP2007 in terms of usability. There should at least be an option to inherit feature configuration from the parent. I shouldn't need to build a custom feature simply so I can use an alternate css and not have to activate the publishing feature on every single sub site.